# Do I need to have enterprise server in order to have multiple data sources in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs, ssrs-2008

I am currently running a single server setup of SSRS on MSSQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition and would like to know if I can have multiple data sources in this type of setup.

The reason I ask this is that I currently have a different SSRS setup (single server) where the primary reporting server sits in one state (physical, as in cross country) it then pulls data from several different data sources, some local, some sitting in a completely different state, it then renders the data and pushes it all to the client locations which are in a completely different state then the SSRS or SQL server data sources (Think a very large triangle with SSRS at one corner, SQL at another, and Clients at the third).

Our goal is to move to an Enterprise setup eventually, but as a stop gap I would like to move the SSRS and all SQL connections to the same physical data center so as to reduce bottlenecks. My problem is that I have been told from local sources that SSRS needs to have an Enterprise edition version of SQL Server in order to maintain multiple Data Sources. As it is not possible (nor feasible) to have all data sitting on one database (XD), this would require a further license upgrade on this server which is likely not to be approved due to a further GDW project on the horizon.

Cheers

Comment: Thank M.Ali I will keep that in mind in the future, I didn't even know that existed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific requirement for Enterprise Edition, though Express will not work either, which leaves Standard as your realistic option.

See [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#Reporting).

Express Edition does have limitations:

**Allowed data source SQL Server edition** is **SQL Server Express only**.

The is no **Remote and non-relational data source support**.

Web and Workgroup have similar limitations.

You can see from that list there is no specific limitation against the number of Data Sources.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's true - the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.ASPX#Reporting) doesn't explicitly say either way but nothing I see would prevent you from having multiple data sources in SSRS on Standard Edition.